# In ios-charts how to set the maximum value for y-axis?

Tags: ios, swift, mpandroidchart, ios-charts

I am using ios-charts to display a Horizontal BarChart with one value like this:

```
 var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: self.deductible!.deductiblePaid, xIndex: 0)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        let chartDataSet =    BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Deductible")
        let chartData = BarChartData( xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: chartDataSet)


        self.horizontalBarChart!.data = chartData
        self.horizontalBarChart!.leftAxis.customAxisMax = 3000.0
        self.horizontalBarChart!.leftAxis.startAtZeroEnabled = false

        chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.vordiplom()
```

I have tried to set the maximum value for the YAxis but its not effecting the graph. 
Edit: Please see the screenshot here : http://postimg.org/image/ogoj2t02f/
What I need is the bar should show the upper limit upto 3000 (or an amount specified dynamically) instead of the calculated upper limit.

I changed some code to make it, here is what I have currently:

```
self.horizontalBarChart!.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

        self.horizontalBarChart!.setVisibleYRangeMaximum(3000, axis: ChartYAxis.AxisDependency.Left)
        self.horizontalBarChart!.descriptionText = ""
        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: self.deductible!.deductiblePaid, xIndex: 0)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        let chartDataSet =    BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: " ")
        self.horizontalBarChart!.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."
        self.horizontalBarChart!.setViewPortOffsets(left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0);
        let chartData = BarChartData( xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: chartDataSet)

        self.horizontalBarChart!.autoScaleMinMaxEnabled = false
        self.horizontalBarChart!.data = chartData
        self.horizontalBarChart!.leftAxis.axisMaximum = 1600
        self.horizontalBarChart!.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 00
        self.horizontalBarChart!.rightAxis.axisMaximum = 1600
        //self.horizontalBarChart!.leftAxis.customAxisMax = 3000.0
        //self.horizontalBarChart!.leftAxis.startAtZeroEnabled = false

        chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.vordiplom()
        self.horizontalBarChart!.xAxis.labelPosition = .Top

        self.horizontalBarChart!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 189/255, green: 195/255, blue: 199/255, alpha: 1)
        self.horizontalBarChart!.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0)
```

Please let me know if I am unclear and you need more details. This has been more challenging that I thought it would be! Any help here would be much appreciated.

**Second Edit:**  I have the following code now :

```
 func setHorizontalBarChartData() {

        self.horizontalBarChart!.descriptionText = ""
        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: 900, xIndex: 0)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        let chartDataSet =    BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: " ")
        self.horizontalBarChart!.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."
        //self.horizontalBarChart!.setViewPortOffsets(left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0);
        let deductible = [" "]
        let chartData = BarChartData( xVals: deductible, dataSet: chartDataSet)
        self.horizontalBarChart!.data = chartData
        self.horizontalBarChart!.leftAxis.startAtZeroEnabled = false
        self.horizontalBarChart!.rightAxis.startAtZeroEnabled = false
        self.horizontalBarChart!.rightAxis.customAxisMax = 3000
        self.horizontalBarChart!.rightAxis.customAxisMin = 10
        chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.vordiplom()
        self.horizontalBarChart!.xAxis.labelPosition = .Top
        self.horizontalBarChart!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 189/255, green: 195/255, blue: 199/255, alpha: 1)
        self.horizontalBarChart!.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0)
    }
```

I am still getting the same thing : http://postimg.org/image/ogoj2t02f/
What I need is only one bar with values upto 3000 and a bar chart coming upto 900. 
Could you please help ?

Comment: I have tried both customAxisMax and axisMax properties but they have not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`customAxisMax` should be able to help you. It works fine on my side.

What you might be missing is, you are setting `leftAxis`, but you should know there is `rightAxis` as well. I am not sure which you are using.

If you take a look `BarLineChartViewBase.swift'`, there is code in

`internal override func calcMinMax`:

```
_leftAxis.axisMaximum = !isnan(_leftAxis.customAxisMax) ? _leftAxis.customAxisMax : (maxLeft + topSpaceLeft)
_rightAxis.axisMaximum = !isnan(_rightAxis.customAxisMax) ? _rightAxis.customAxisMax : (maxRight + topSpaceRight)
_leftAxis.axisMinimum = !isnan(_leftAxis.customAxisMin) ? _leftAxis.customAxisMin : (minLeft - bottomSpaceLeft)
_rightAxis.axisMinimum = !isnan(_rightAxis.customAxisMin) ? _rightAxis.customAxisMin : (minRight - bottomSpaceRight)
```

It reads `customAxisMax` or `customAxisMin` once you set it. You need to double check which axis you are using.

Edit for your second edit:

I just change the demo code, is it what you want?

Code in ios-charts demo, try it in your demo code:

```
- (void)setDataCount:(int)count range:(double)range
{
    NSMutableArray *xVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [xVals addObject:months[0]];

    NSMutableArray *yVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [yVals addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:900 xIndex:0]];

    BarChartDataSet *set1 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithYVals:yVals label:@"DataSet"];
    set1.barSpace = 0.35;

    NSMutableArray *dataSets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [dataSets addObject:set1];

    BarChartData *data = [[BarChartData alloc] initWithXVals:xVals dataSets:dataSets];
    [data setValueFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:10.f]];
    _chartView.leftAxis.startAtZeroEnabled = NO;
    _chartView.rightAxis.startAtZeroEnabled = NO;
    _chartView.rightAxis.enabled = NO;
    _chartView.leftAxis.customAxisMax = 3000;
    _chartView.leftAxis.customAxisMin = 10;

    _chartView.data = data;
}
```

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Winzergo . I have added some more details on what I am trying to do. Please see my edits.

Comment: I tried setting the customAxisMax for both x and y axis but that did not fully effect. It  increased upto 1200 (previously it was 1000). Since I have a small rectangle for the graph view, could it be that I need to scale it to fit ?

Comment: I tried with the ios-charts demo code, customAxisMin and customAxisMax works fine on my side. Have you changed the rendering code? Do you mind provide a sample project? You can try the demo horizontal bar chart code: `
    _chartView.leftAxis.startAtZeroEnabled = NO;
    _chartView.rightAxis.startAtZeroEnabled = NO;
    _chartView.leftAxis.customAxisMax = 100;
    _chartView.leftAxis.customAxisMin = 10;
    _chartView.data = data;`  it will limit the leftAxis to 10~100

Comment: BTW, you can try to debug the swift code, it will give you more information.

Comment: `setVisibleYRangeMaximum` will not limit your axis min or max value. use customAxisMax instead. I have uploaded the screenshot on my side, is it what you want? You can try from the demo code, much easier to find out where goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I changed the code as per your suggestion, please see the code in the edited question, also, I am adding what I am getting and what I want. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `only one bar with values upto 3000 and a bar chart coming upto 900`. what 3000 and 900 are, explicitly? But I have update my answer, is it what you want? There is no magic, just simple configuration.

Comment: I got it ! I just copy pasted your code and converted it to Swift and it worked! I am not sure why it was not working before. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: glad it works. You can check where's the difference. What I guess is you are using right axis while I use left one. It should be consistent

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. On a horizontal bar chart,I set a customAxisMax to 600 and a customAxisMin to 0, startAtZeroEnabled = NO, and I have values equal to 33, some 0s and a 50. The issue is that the chart does not scale using my custom maximum value. It scales using the maximum value of my data set, which is 50.

Comment: @Konrad I tried with latest ChartsDemo 2.1.6, I can have a customAxisMax=600 effect without problem. Which axis you are setting? right or left? you have to make sure it's the same y axis when you set it, also update your code maybe.

Comment: Thanks Wingzero. I do use the right axis, and I set it for the right axis. But setting customAxisMax for the LEFT axis even though I disabled it (leftAxis.enabled = NO) made things work.

Comment: really? have you set dataSet axis dependency?

Answer (score 5):

If the upper and lower y-axis values are not shown as expected, make sure,

1. you set the `customAxisMax` and `customAxisMin` on both left and right of the y-axis.
2. you set the `customAxisMax` and `customAxisMax` before you set the `.data` of the chart view.
3. you set both x and y-axis' `startAtZeroEnabled` to false. And you set `startAtZeroEnabled` before you set the `.data` of the chart view.

It took me a few hours to figure those out. Hope it could save you some.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have solved the issue as per the original answer.